# Is "there is a crack in the kettle liner" a correct/clear expression?

Tags: vocabulary

I am trying to describe the defect of my newly arrived electric kettle. There is a black spot in the liner, looks like a piece of the coating layer has fell off. What is the most simple and clear description? Can I say "there is a crack in the kettle liner"?

Comment: Yes, that's fine to say. Maybe add in some more description like size, length, location of the crack when explaining it to the manufacturer.

Comment: I don't get this question. Does it really need ELU to advise whether you should use *"is"*, or some more circumspect form such as *"seems to be"* in a context like this?

Comment: I'm not clear what is meant by a 'liner' in a kettle. What's the kettle made of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may rather say

**There *appears to be* a crack in the kettle liner.**

It appears, from your question, that you are unsure exactly what the problem is, but that you are certain that the kettle is defective. Providing additional description, as amanda suggested, would probably be helpful in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Make THEM own it.  "There's a crack in your kettle liner."  This is a common sales technique--make the problem theirs to solve.